# Same prefix can be added in two separate http listeners

Tags: c#, http-proxy, httplistener, port80

I have to create two separate listeners each provides support for some files.
Listener 1 is used to provide support for some XML files.
Listener 2 is used to provide support for some HTML files.

I want to create these two listeners separately.

But I want to access both the files via browser. So can I add IP:80 port as prefix in both listeners. Is it possible. My primary aim is to access all the files in browser(without specifiying the port, like,

```
171.10.1.1/myFile.xml
171.10.1.1/File.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Alternatively you can also specify unique path prefixes for XML and HTML files, e.g. like this:

```
http://171.10.1.1/xml/
```

and

```
http://171.10.1.1/html/
```

The nice thing of HttpListeners is you are free to write your own handlers.